# Public Property Data Binding failing in Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

My code behind file has its corresponding View Model as a public property for one of my Windows. I tried to data bind my ViewModel with the UI Elements in XAML but I always get error messages for that. However, when I try to create data bind using code, it works without any issues. I am really confused as to why this is happening and would like some guidance on what I am doing wrong.

### Scenario 1 - Data binding fails when done in xaml

ProductInfoWindow.xaml:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid Name="grdProd" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewModel}">
        <TextBox Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Product.Name}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ProductInfoWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ProductInfoWindow : Window
{
    public ProductInfoViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public ProductInfo()
    {
        ViewModel = new ProductInfoViewModel(...);
    }
}
```

Error Messages in Output Window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ViewModel' property not 
found on 'object' ''Grid' (Name='grdProd')'. BindingExpression:Path=ViewModel; 
DataItem='Grid' (Name='grdProd'); target element is 'Grid' (Name='grdProd'); target 
property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

### Scenario 2 - Data binding works when done in code

ProductInfoWindow.xaml:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid Name="grdProd">
        <TextBox Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Product.Name}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ProductInfoWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ProductInfoWindow : Window
{
    public ProductInfoViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public ProductInfo()
    {
        ViewModel = new ProductInfoViewModel(...);
        grdProd.DataContext = ViewModel;
    }
}
```

### Edit (09/08/2013)

ProductInfoViewModel.cs

```
public class ProductInfoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

    private Product m_product;

    public Product Product
    {
        get
        {
            return m_product;
        }

        set
        {
            m_product = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Product"));
        }
    }

    public ProductInfoViewModel(...)
    {
        Product = new Product(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush, I have added error messages right at the end of Scenario 1 under sub section "Error Messages in Output Window".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is telling you that the `ViewModel` property can't be found on the `Grid` `'grdProd'`, which is a fair point, because your `Viewmodel` is a public property defined on your `ProductInfoWindow` class.

Try setting the `Datacontext` at the `Window` level instead (adapting your example):

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewModel}" ...>
    <Grid Name="grdProd"> 
        <TextBox Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Product.Name}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I am not getting any errors anymore. But none of the UI controls is displaying any information. I double checked that I followed your fix exactly as what you said. Your answer makes a lot of sense, so I am not sure why it is not happening.

Comment: Where is your Viewmodel initialised? If initialisation occurs after the `Window` is created, the UI will not necessarily update, you'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to inform your UI that changes to the bound objects are occuring. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist

Comment: Chris, I added my implementation of ProductInfoViewModel above in the "Edit" section. I tried debugging through the ViewModel last night and here is what I found. My PropertyChanged event handler is always null. This surprised me because I thought the xaml "Window DataContext=..." line would cause the PropertyChanged event handler to be initialized or something.

Comment: If you're binding your window to a null `DataContext` which is being initialised later, your `Window` won't be aware that its `ViewModel` object has changed (and won't update the `DataContext`. You could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Window`, but that's not a great fix. It would be better to instantiate your `ViewModel` before your view is created (you could do this before the call to `InitializeComponent();` in your `Window` constructor.